# Storing data in SQLite database after closing session in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I am building an iPhone app using Objective-C that stores data in a SQLite database.  The problem I'm having is that when my application is running, I'm able to make certain changes to the data in the table.  Specifically, I need to allow the user to click on a button and select certain restaurants from the list as being a "favourite" (true), or "unfavourite" (false).

When my simulator is running, the code works fine.  However, when I close my session and restart the app, the changes that I made in my previous session are not saved.  Here is the relevant block of code:

```
- (void) addFavourite:(NSString *)rName{


sqlite3 *database;

NSString *updateString = nil;
NSString *trueStatement = @"true";

NavButtonAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([delegate.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    updateString = @"UPDATE gtarestaurant set isFavourite = ? WHERE name = ?";
    const char *sqlStatement = [updateString UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [trueStatement UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [rName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

}

}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?  It appears that my problem is committing my changes to the database, after the user makes them

Comment: Where do you load the database? Do you create it in code or do you copy a resource file?  I suspect you might be overwriting your database, please post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Update error: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

instead of:

```
    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


    }
```

There are many ways the update could be failing such as the table not being there, or a field name being misspelled.  This should give you an error telling you why the update did not process.  If you don't want the app to stop use NSLog instead of NSAssert.

Also: you should have an else statement coupled with your `if (sqlite3_open())` to notify you or the user that the database wasn't opened properly.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  My code is not generating any errors.  Rather, as I said earlier, the changes to the database that I'm making are not committing past a user's sessions.  I tried implementing your solution, and unfortunately my problem still persists.  I'm suspicious that the problem may be related to how I am finalizing my statements.  Could that be it?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Are you checking the database itself to make sure that your changes are actually being made?  As long as you are not deleting the app off the simulator, the database should maintain the changes.  If you're sure the database is actually changing after that method is called it could be that your code is overwriting the database somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks once again for your prompt reply.  I did some more testing, and found out that my app never gets past the following line of code:  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
Do you see why this is the case?  I've checked the database, and the updates aren't being made when I check from the sqlite console, which confirms my finding.  In other words, the changes are never written to the table.  Do you see what's wrong?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Same deal, after that if statement add an else statement: 'NSAssert1(0, @"Error: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));' This should output more information for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for all of your solutions.  I found out that the problem was that the changes I thought I had made to my SQLite table had not gone through, and therefore my code was never writing any updates to the table.  I had to actually go and make the changes via a database explorer to the location of the database being used by the iPhone simulator as part of the app in order for the code to correctly process the updates.  Thanks very much Deepmist, and theChrisKent for taking the time to post your solutions.  I really appreciate it.  Take care.